# Problems with using checkbox with Thymeleaf

Tags: html, templates, checkbox, thymeleaf

I'm having problems with using checkbox with Thymleaf.

My Form has a List of object "AssignFlag" with name "assignFlagList".

```
List<AssignFlagForm> assignFlagList;
```

object AssignFlagForm has 3 fields:

```
    String codeValue;

    String codeKey;

    public boolean isChecked;
```

I want to create checkboxes for each `AssignFlagForm`, and post `true` value for each `AssignFlag` that is checked on the screen.

my Thymeleaf template:

```
                 <span th:each="assignFlag, stat : *{assignFlagList}">
                            <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{assignFlagList[__${stat.index}__].isChecked}"
                                   th:value="*{'TRUE'}" style="margin-right: 0;" />
                            <label th:for="${'assignFlagList' + stat.index + '.isChecked1'}" th:text="${assignFlag.codeKey}" style="font-weight: normal;">
                            </label>
                        </span>
```

and I wrote this referring to the official document of Thymeleaf
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#checkbox-fields

It doesn't work and I don't know why.
Error code is

```
Error during execution of processor org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputCheckboxFieldTagProcessor
```

but I still can't figure out.

Could somebody please help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are your getters and setters on the javaObject really named `isIsChecked()` and `setIsChecked()`?  What is the entire error message?

Comment: Actually, the setter is `setChecked` and the getter is not working. (`AssignForm` has @getter and @setter annotations).

I have some sample codes from another application to which I referred to when I wrote this code, and in that source, the form has the field `isChecked` as  `BooleanValue`. Can this be the reason of my codes not working? 

I will add the error message afterwords.

Comment: I Changed
`th:field="*{assignFlagList[__${stat.index}__].isChecked}"`
to
`th:field="*{assignFlagList[__${stat.index}__].Checked}"`
and it worked!!

thank you so much for giving me a hint. I was stuck for days.

Still, I cannot figure out why the getter is not working (different issue), so if you have any additional information on that I'd appreciate a lot.

thank you again

Comment: Update: I changed the type of the field from `boolean` to `Boolean` and the getter/setter is now working properly. Now I can keep   `th:field="{assignFlagList[__${stat.index}__].isChecked}"` !